# Is it Possible to run Spring application in oracle R12.2 ebiz environment?

Tags: spring, oracle

Is it Possible to run Spring application in oracle R12.2  ebiz environment ?

In my project we are using plain java/jsp code to deploy changes in ebiz environment.

Answer (score 0):

Not direcly. You have to connect to a J2E Server via a Java Connector.

Comment: Can you explore bit more  ?

Comment: so via java connector i can access a spring view from ebiz responsibility ?